# Coin Flip animation with number count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I want to use an animation of counting number with coin flip effect, means with my number count i want to flip my circle horizontally 360 deg.

I am using below code for it :

kindly help! Thanks in advance

```js
(function ($) {
    
    $.fn.CountUpCircle = function(options){

     var self = this; 

  var settings = $.extend({
   duration: 1000 //ms
  }, options);

  var toCount = parseInt(this.html());
  console.log("Count up to " + toCount);

  var i   = 0;
  var step = settings.duration / toCount;
  console.log("Step duration " + step);

  var displayNumber = function() {
   i++;
   self.html(i);
   if (i < toCount) {
    setTimeout(displayNumber, step);
   }
  };

  displayNumber();
 }

}(jQuery));

   $(document).ready(function(){             
                $('#count-box').CountUpCircle({
                    duration: 1500
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Minimal-jQuery-Count-Up-Plugin-CoutUpCircle/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="jquery-script-menu">
 
<h1 style="margin-top:150px; color:#fff;" align="center">CountUpCircle jQuery Plugin Demo</h1>
 
<div id="count-box">23</div>
</div>
```